# Checkbox in Formic Default Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, material-ui, formik

When I passed the initial state the value of the checkbox must be checked according to my knowledge but I don't know why values are showing empty. I think I am doing wrong?

Empty Checkboxes Despite the initial value are set.

```
const initialValue = {
        department:departments?.map((x:any)=>{
      return x._id
    }),
    designation:designations?.map((x:any)=>{
      return x._id
    }),
      };
 const handleSubmit = (values: any) => {
    console.log(values)
let value = {
       Selecteddepartment: values.department,
       designations: values.designation,
     };
     console.log(value.Selecteddepartment,"dsdsd")
     console.log(value,"values after submit ")
     callAxios({
       url: `${CONFIRM_DEPARTMENTS_DESIGNATIONS}`,
       method: "post",
       data: value,
     }).then((res: any) => {
       dispatch(showSnackbar({ message: res.message }))
       navigate(START);
     });
  };
 <Grid
                  container
                  spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}
                  columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }} >
                  {departments?.map((department: any, i) => (
                    <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={i}>
                      <Item>
                        <label
                          style={{ wordBreak: "break-word" }}
                          key={department?._id}>
                          <Field
                            as={Checkbox}
                            id="department"
                            name="department"
                            value={department?._id}
                            style={{ display: "table" }}
                            checked={department?._id}
                             checked={department?._id}
                                                    />
                          {department?.Name}
                        </label>
                      </Item>
                    </Grid>
                  ))}
                </Grid>]
```